# Git shows branches what already deleted

Tags: git

When I give a command: `git branch` it shows me the following:

```
HSM2-585
* POLTODO-111
POLTODO-283
develop
master
```

But when in console I press the `TAB` key it lists me the following:

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

```
develop               HSM2-585              origin/develop        origin/master      origin/#TODO-269              
FETCH_HEAD            master                origin/HEAD           origin/#TODO-111   origin/TODO-283    TODO-111           
HEAD                  ORIG_HEAD             origin/HSM2-585       origin/TODO-111    origin/TODO-286    TODO-283
```

So old branches what I've already deleted from local and remote too appears.

The funniest that I could checkout the `origin/TODO-286` for example. I am using Gitlab.

How do I purge these old and deleted branches?

Comment: I think the problem here is that git still thinks these branches exists, so in reality, they're actually not deleted after all. If someone does a `git push --all` and doesn't use `git fetch --prune`, they will have old copies of the branches that they push back to the server. Can *you* do a `git fetch --prune` and see if it clears up on your end before we go further?

Comment: Does `git branch -a` show those branches anywhere?

Comment: @larsks Yes. There are the branches with white color, the active is green, and after that there are all the deleted branches with red color.

Comment: download the repository remotely again and the problem will disappear ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @LasseVågsætherKarlsen said in a comment, you need to use `git fetch --prune`. What you're seeing is remote-tracking branches, these are in the format `<remote>/<branch-name>` such as `origin/TODO-111`.

[The documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch#git-fetch--p) for `git fetch` with the `-p or --prune` flag says:

> Before fetching, remove any remote-tracking references that no longer exist on the remote.

So using this will clear out those old and unwanted tracking branches. `git branch --all` should then be clean of these branches. As will `git branch [TAB]`

Comment: Worth noting: you can configure `git fetch` to apply `--prune` by default, by setting `fetch.prune` to `true` in your Git configuration (globally or per-repo, your choice).

Comment: thank  you, tomorrow I will test it, if it works, I will accept and upvote.